# mongoDB cluster structure and costs

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongoDB and I use kubernetes in order to provision mongoDB.

I have understood that the deployment of mongo is divided into config/mongos/mongo-data-nodes

each of the config and the data nodes requires 3 replicas.
data nodes will be divided into shards.

this will give me a very a large amount of running mongo instances as a big potion of these instances will not be functioning as they will just be replicas.

is there a way to run multiple replicas on the same instance?
is it recommended to run multiple replicas on the same instance?

how do you manage your mongoDB cluster in order to avoid reaching dozens of mongoDB instances where only a portion of them are actually usable?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: This question would be better suited for DBA StackExchange since it is about deployment rather than programming. Secondary members of your replica set have a definite function: they provide data redundancy and fault tolerance. These instances can also be used for queries or reporting if eventual consistency is tolerable for your use case. You can certainly run multiple instances on the same host, but this is generally not recommended for production deployments. The instances will be competing for the same host resources and a single host failure will affect multiple instances in your cluster.